# Python regular expression for non-latin characters not working

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have some sentences like the following

```
w = "Chiang Wei-kuo (traditional Chinese: 蔣緯國; simplified Chinese: 蒋纬国; pinyin: Jiǎng Wěiguó, or Wego Chiang; and Nadezhda Nikitichna Mikhalkova (Russian: Надежда Никитична Михалкова;"
```

and I am using the following regular expression to capture non-latin words `(蔣緯國, 蒋纬国, Надежда Никитична Михалкова)`

```
for match in re.finditer(r'(?<=:\s)\W+(?=;)', w):
    print(match[0])
```

So I am trying to capture any non-word characters `\W` between the symbol `:` and the symbol `;` . But it doesn't seem to be working. I also tried substituting `\W` with `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but still it doesn't work. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a flag `re.ASCII`

```
import re

w = "Chiang Wei-kuo (traditional Chinese: 蔣緯國; simplified Chinese: 蒋纬国; pinyin: Jiǎng Wěiguó, or Wego Chiang; and Nadezhda Nikitichna Mikhalkova (Russian: Надежда Никитична Михалкова;"
print(re.findall(r'(?<=:\s)\W+(?=;)', w, re.ASCII))
```

Output

```
['蔣緯國', '蒋纬国', 'Надежда Никитична Михалкова']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```py
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=:\s)[^\s\dA-Za-z_][^;]*(?=;)', w)

['蔣緯國', '蒋纬国', 'Надежда Никитична Михалкова']
```

`\W` is unicode compliant to match any non-word unicode character only.